# Initialize weka Instance with default values

Tags: initialization, weka, default-value

Is it possible to create a weka `Instance` object containing all default values (e.g., all `0`s)?

By instantiating it as follows:

```
Instance newInstance = new Instance(dimension);
```

I just obtain a vector having non-specified values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default parameter to do it. Apart from looping through attributes and initializing with setValue, a good alternative could be to create a template instance with all default values and use the shallow copy method ( .copy() ) for each new instance (Instance implements Copyable).